# Cascaded persist not working (Doctrine ORM + Symfony 2)

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I started working with symfony several months ago and there is one thing keeps bothering me all the time. It is when I have a one-to-many relationship in Doctrine and I try to insert something into the database. Here's an example:

**Broker.orm.yml**

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Broker:
    type: entity
    table: brokers
    repositoryClass: BrokerRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        slug:
            type: string
            length: 64
    oneToMany:
        accountTypes:
            targetEntity: Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\AccountType
            mappedBy: broker
            cascade: ["persist"]
```

**AccountType.orm.yml**

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\AccountType:
    type: entity
    table: account_types
    repositoryClass: AccountTypeRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        slug:
            type: string
            length: 64
    manyToOne:
        broker:
            targetEntity: Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Broker
            inversedBy: accountTypes
            joinColumn:
                name: broker_id
                referencedColumn: id
```

**Then is try to save it to the database like this.**

```
$accountType = new AccountType();
$accountType->setName("blabla");
// additional data to accountType

$broker->addAccountType($accountType);

$em->persist($broker);
$em->flush();
```

The strange thing is that it works prefrectly with only one tiny problem. Broker is updated, and AccountType is inserted into the database but **the accountType doesn't have any relations with the Broker.** In other words, when I check in the database the `broker_id` fields reamains untouched and contains `NULL`.

If I add `$accountType->setBroker($broker)` manually, it works. But I started to use Sonata Admin Bundle where there is much more complicated to do this and I don't really need a complex admin system. So I just want a fast development on it and without this "feature" it's nearly impossible.

And anyways, if I add something to a collection of an Object, it should know which object is its parent, right? :)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Is your Broker object `$broker` already known by doctrine (i.e. being fetched from a repository) before you add `$accountType`?

Comment: What happens if you persist the newly created $accountType before using the setter to add to broker? $em->persist($accountType);

Comment: That's what the cascade option is for basically - he doesn't want to explicitly persist the related entity.

Comment: $broker is an object known by doctrine, fetched from database.

Comment: And yes, I don't want to persist the newly created accountType before. That's why I want to use cascaded persist.

Comment: Check the doctrine documentation: Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) In your specific case accountType is the owning side.

Comment: Yes, the owning side is $broker, I know that. But $broker changes, because it has a new element in its accountType collection. That's why doctrine saves both $broker and $accountType into the database. The only problem is that the newly inserted accountType has NULL value of broker_id, so it is not linked to the Broker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Broker
{
    public function addAccountType($accountType)
    {
        $this->accountTypes[] = $accountType;

        // *** This is what you are missing ***
        $accountType->setBroker($this);
```

Comment: Thank you! I generated Entity classes with doctrine and I didn't think  of this small change in the modell classes. (Maybe there is an option in doctrine for this? It seems to be a quite common deal for me.)

Comment: One more thing, it works when i test it like the way i wrote in my question. But it doesn't work in Sonata Admin bundle when i add something to the collection. :((