# Symfony One To Many not linking parent

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Quiz structure with 3 entities:

- Quiz has Questions (OneToMany)
- Question has Quiz (ManyToOne)
- Question has Answers (OneToMany)
- Answer has Question (ManyToOne)

The code looks like such:

Quiz Entity

```
class Quiz
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="quiz", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $questions;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->questions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addQuestion(\Cariboo\QuizBundle\Entity\Question $questions)
    {
        $questions->setQuiz( $this );
        // die(); Not dying here...
        $this->questions[] = $questions;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeQuestion(\Cariboo\QuizBundle\Entity\Question $questions)
    {
        $this->questions->removeElement($questions);
    }

    public function getQuestions()
    {
        return $this->questions;
    }
}
```

Question Entity

```
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="question", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $answers;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cariboo\QuizBundle\Entity\Quiz", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $quiz;

    public function addAnswer(\Cariboo\QuizBundle\Entity\Answer $answers)
    {
        $answers->setQuestion( $this );
        $this->answers[] = $answers;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAnswer(\Cariboo\QuizBundle\Entity\Answer $answers)
    {
        $this->answers->removeElement($answers);
    }

    public function getAnswers()
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }

    public function setQuiz(\Cariboo\QuizBundle\Entity\Quiz $quiz = null)
    {
        $this->quiz = $quiz;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuiz()
    {
        return $this->quiz;
    }
}
```

Answer entity

```
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cariboo\QuizBundle\Entity\Question")
     */
    private $question;

    public function setQuestion(\Cariboo\QuizBundle\Entity\Question $question = null)
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }
}
```

I cascade persist them.

I configured my setters as explained in [Cascaded persist not working (Doctrine ORM + Symfony 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605578/cascaded-persist-not-working-doctrine-orm-symfony-2)

The addAnswer gets executed and for answers, the Question is set properly. However the addQuestion does not set the quiz.

[image of what gets dumped upon sending the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS4OE.png)

I can add a `foreach` in my controller but I am not satisfied with this, as I feel I am not exploiting symfony's power. ( No duplicate of [Entity doesn't associate correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578004/entity-doesnt-associate-correctly) )

```
    if ( $form->isValid() ) {
        foreach ( $quiz->getQuestions() as $question ) {
            $question->setQuiz( $quiz );
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist( $quiz );
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl( 'quiz_show', array(
            'slug' => $quiz->getSlug()
        ) ) );
    }
```

I cannot figure out why the `addQuestion` does not get executed.

### Edit

My `Quiz` form

```
    $builder
        ->add( 'questions', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new QuestionType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'prototype_name' => '__qst_prot__'
        ) )
    ;
```

Partial builder of `Question`

```
    $builder
        ->add( 'question', 'text' )
        ->add( 'answers', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new AnswerType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'prototype_name' => '__asw_prot__'
        ) );
```

My `Answer form`

```
$builder
        ->add( 'answer', 'text' )
        ->add( 'correct' )
    ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity doesn't associate correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578004/entity-doesnt-associate-correctly)

Comment: i think that `collection` type creates problem here. How about setting `by_reference` to false (in `Quiz` form)?

Comment: Setting `by_reference` works wonders! I have no idea why it worked for Answers without it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in `collection` form type. You need to set `by_reference` to `false` if you want to call parent entity setter.

Symfony docs:

`Similarly, if you're using the CollectionType field where your underlying collection data is an object (like with Doctrine's ArrayCollection), then by_reference must be set to false if you need the adder and remover (e.g. addAuthor() and removeAuthor()) to be called.`

Read more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

Comment: Yet I can `die` in `addAnswer` but not in `addQuestion`. The similar appearance of `Answer` and `Question` also startles me.

Comment: I added the form builder in an edit ;) I did not add the `js` that generates the fields from the prototypes.